# pypy 3 with Numpy - what is the latest on this?

Tags: python, numpy, pypy

I realize that there have been other questions similar to mine asked but I'm trying to get the latest info on this so that I can stop chasing my own tail if need be.

I have a project that runs on python 3 with numpy. I'd like to see it run under a faster framework so I've considered using pypy 3. At one point, numpy was incompatible with pypy 3. Is that still the case? Are there one options for python 3 and performance gains that don't involve pypy?

Comment: What are the bottlenecks in your code?  Pure numpy operations?  Iterative stuff that can't written in proper numpy? Operations that should be compiled?  `numba` and `cython` get frequent questions, but often because users blindly throw them at their code and hope for miracles.

Comment: ["For now, NumPyPy does not work with PyPy3*, and is not complete"](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy). On the other hand, you should [profile your code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) and check for tools and/or techniques for your bottlenecks. Blind optimization is always discouraged